# jQuery simple Data Pass HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a HTML form, I'd like to achieve once the submit button hit, then goes to a confirmation page. The confirmation page get the data from form page.

As my form validation is used by jQuery, for example I have a variable name is `VISITORNAME` 
How to make the conformation page shows "THANK YOU `VISITORNAME`"

I did research, could not find a simple easy way to do it.

Comment: +1 for all the -1's without comment. I agree it is a stupid question, but -1ing it without comments will not make the OP learn anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have many ways to do that, one is to add something to the url when the form is submitted and read with js in the other page (this does not involve server side coding)

```
$(form).submit(function() {
  $(this).action += '#visitorname=whatever'
});
```

Then in the form you can get the visitorname from the url

```
var name = window.location.href.replace(/^.*#visitorname=/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Most forms use a server-side language, such as PHP or ASP.net. I suggest you read PHP's 'Dealing with forms' tutorial:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Make the comfirmation page a PHP page, and send some GET or POST values from the form with it.

Then `echo` your message:

```
echo 'Thank you, '.$_POST['visitorname'].', your form has been submitted';
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
**html**
 <form name='ff' id='test' action="javascript:void(0);">
 <span id='msg'></span>
 <input type='text' id='name'>
 <input type="submit" value='submit'>
 </form>

  **jquery**
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#test').submit(function(){
  if($('#name').val()!=''){
   $('#msg').html('Your custom message');
 }

});
});
```