# simple Data Pass between HTML, Url static

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, I have already asked this question here: [jQuery simple Data Pass HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669506/jquery-simple-data-pass-html)

I have 1/2 achieved my goal, 
I am using `window.location.href` to pass the variable "`VISITORNAME`"
the Url looks `http://myurl/sent#someone@email.com` (`VISITORNAME`)

then I used window.location.href.replace to get someone@email.com (`VISITORNAME`)

how possible to make url like static, just like `http://myurl/sent` but still passing the value to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of **GET** you can use **POST** to pass the parameters..

By doing so the parameters will not be reflected in the url..

Try this approach

```
$.post('http://myurl/sent',{ email : VISITORNAME });
```

Comment: after POST, do I still use the way `window.location.href` to GET. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep your URL simple and clean you would need to change your form method from get to post.  However, you'd need to be aware of limitation on how that would affect users hitting the refresh button, bookmarking, etc.